# Tutor Open edX commands

Tags: openedx, edx

what is the actual difference in these 3 commands? Looking for a quick reply. Thank you.

tutor local quickstart | tutor local start | tutor local reboot

#tutor

Answer (score 0):

tutor local quickstart
is what you use the first time you install Tutor.
Then after that you just use
tutor local start
After you have modified any data and saved it with
tutor config save
It is advised to restart your platform to apply those changes with
tutor local reboot